# Localstorage setItem when click on and keep the content reveal even after reload page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, local-storage

I'm trying to localStorage setItem for this script to continue to show the content inside the DIV tag and keep it open even after refreshing the page. Now I got stuck and don't know what to do to make it work.

In this code after clicking on the Click Toggle Div link, the content will reveal and I want it to continue to reveal even I reload the page or until I click on the Click Toggle Div link again.

```js
var getTiming = function (elem) {
    var timing = 350;
    if (elem.classList.contains('show-fast')) {
        timing = 100;
    }
    if (elem.classList.contains('show-slow')) {
        timing = 2000;
    }
    return timing;
};

// Show an element
var show = function (elem) {

    // Get the transition timing
    var timing = getTiming(elem);

    // Get the natural height of the element
    var getHeight = function () {
        elem.style.display = 'block'; // Make it visible
        var height = elem.scrollHeight + 'px'; // Get it's height
        elem.style.display = ''; //  Hide it again
        return height;
    };

    var height = getHeight(); // Get the natural height
    elem.classList.add('is-visible'); // Make the element visible
    elem.style.height = height; // Update the max-height

    // Once the transition is complete, remove the inline max-height so the content can scale responsively
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        elem.style.height = '';
    }, timing);

};

// Hide an element
var hide = function (elem) {

    // Get the transition timing
    var timing = getTiming(elem);

    // Give the element a height to change from
    elem.style.height = elem.scrollHeight + 'px';

    // Set the height back to 0
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        elem.style.height = '0';
    }, 1);

    // When the transition is complete, hide it
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        elem.classList.remove('is-visible');
    }, timing);
  
  

};

// Toggle element visibility
var toggle = function (elem, timing) {

    // If the element is visible, hide it
    if (elem.classList.contains('is-visible')) {
        hide(elem);
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise, show it
    show(elem);

};

// Listen for click events
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    // Make sure clicked element is our toggle
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('toggle')) return;

    // Prevent default link behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get the content
    var content = document.querySelector(event.target.hash);
    if (!content) return;

    // Toggle the content
    toggle(content);

}, false);
```

```css
.toggle-content {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 350ms ease-in-out, opacity 750ms ease-in-out;
}



.toggle-content.is-visible {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a class="toggle" href="#example">Click Toggle Div</a>
</p>

<div class="toggle-content" id="example">
    This content reveals and setItem localStorage to keep this content revealed even after page reload or until I click on  <a class="toggle" href="#example">Click Toggle Div</a> again.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand you well, but if you want to add/remove item from localStorage for toggle, add this:

```js
var getTiming = function (elem) {
    var timing = 350;
    if (elem.classList.contains('show-fast')) {
        timing = 100;
    }
    if (elem.classList.contains('show-slow')) {
        timing = 2000;
    }
    return timing;
};

// Show an element
var show = function (elem) {
    
    //add token to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("toggle", true);
    
    // Get the transition timing
    var timing = getTiming(elem);

    // Get the natural height of the element
    var getHeight = function () {
        elem.style.display = 'block'; // Make it visible
        var height = elem.scrollHeight + 'px'; // Get it's height
        elem.style.display = ''; //  Hide it again
        return height;
    };

    var height = getHeight(); // Get the natural height
    elem.classList.add('is-visible'); // Make the element visible
    elem.style.height = height; // Update the max-height

    // Once the transition is complete, remove the inline max-height so the content can scale responsively
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        elem.style.height = '';
    }, timing);

};

// Hide an element
var hide = function (elem) {

    //remove from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem("toggle")
    
    // Get the transition timing
    var timing = getTiming(elem);

    // Give the element a height to change from
    elem.style.height = elem.scrollHeight + 'px';

    // Set the height back to 0
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        elem.style.height = '0';
    }, 1);

    // When the transition is complete, hide it
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        elem.classList.remove('is-visible');
    }, timing);
  
  

};

// Toggle element visibility
var toggle = function (elem, timing) {

    // If the element is visible, hide it
    if (localStorage.getItem("toggle")) {
        hide(elem);
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise, show it
    show(elem);

};

// Listen for click events
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    // Make sure clicked element is our toggle
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('toggle')) return;

    // Prevent default link behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get the content
    var content = document.querySelector(event.target.hash);
    if (!content) return;

    // Toggle the content
    toggle(content);
  
    

}, false);
```

```css
.toggle-content {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 350ms ease-in-out, opacity 750ms ease-in-out;
}



.toggle-content.is-visible {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a class="toggle" href="#example">Click Toggle Div</a>
</p>

<div class="toggle-content" id="example">
    This content reveals and setItem localStorage to keep this content revealed even after page reload or until I click on  <a class="toggle" href="#example">Click Toggle Div</a> again.
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, After setItem I need the content to keep revealing even after I reload the page. I try this but not seem to work        $(document).ready(function(){localStorage.getItem("toggle")&&$(".toggle-content").css("display","block")});